# Why does the row class make my outer div fit to size

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am defining some html that has a div box surrounding an image. I want this box to automatically size to frame the image exactly. I found the following code gives me what I want:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="my-box" style="height: 100%;">
        <div data-sink="reveal"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background-size: contain;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gf2t9r1/)

However, when I try removing the row class I suddenly lose this effect but I have no idea why. So the exact same code with the row class removed causes the box to stretch the full width of the screen:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fill">
    <div>
      <div class="my-box" style="height: 100%;">
        <div data-sink="reveal"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background-size: contain;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So my question is how can I get my box to frame my image correctly without the need to use the row class?

Comment: row should only contain columns `col-*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because row class takes
display: flex;

add to fill class
display: flex;

Like this, its better to do in css file but here just to show an example.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fill" style="display: flex">
      <div class="my-box" style="height: 100%;">
        <div data-sink="reveal"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background-size: contain;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pease